# How do you OR two numbers without left shifting first?

Tags: c, hex, bit

Let's take two numbers, `15` and `14`. In hexadecimal, they are `0x0f`, and `0x0e`. Because of the padding zeros, you have to left shift 4 bits in order to get `e`. This is probably because the smallest representable size is one byte, meaning that the numbers are contained in only half the byte. Is it possible to store just the last 4 bits of these numbers?

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what your question is.

Comment: The or Operator is | and you do not need to do a left shift to OR.

Answer (score 1):

`OR` is just a bitwise instruction that asks if there is `at least one 1` then you would get a `1` other wise a `0` the truth table would look like this:

```
 a   b    (a|b)  => a OR b   the | denotes or
---------------
 0   0      0
 1   0      1
 0   1      1
 1   1      1
```

There is no shifting necessary

If you have `15|14` you would then get `15`

```
    0000   1111   // 15
OR  0000   1110   // 14
  --------------
    0000   1111   = 15
```

Comment: Ahem, `(15|14) == 15`...

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to shift left before ORing. So to OR two numbers a and b, you write: a|b.